# How to hide address bar in bubblewrap

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, bubblewrap

I have an PWA application created using ionic & angular
and then created .aab file using following link.
https://developers.google.com/codelabs/pwa-in-play#0

After that installed it using command
bubblewrap install
on my device , I don't see any address bar on top and no errors of assetlinks.json which is usually there if you don't have assetlinks.json but when I deploy it on play store and install it , I do see address bar without any error.

Please guide/advice.

I am able to see the assetlinks.json when I do hit

https://{my domain}/.well-known/assetlinks.json

so there is no error of assetlinks but I still see address bar at top.

Comment: How did you generate your assetlinks.json? Also, have you tried using Peter's Asset Links Tool (available in the play store)? Sounds like it might be due to missing or invalid SHA-256 fingerprints. Try that tool first and verify the result matches your existing assetlinks.json. If that doesn't work, try regenerating your assetlinks.json with `bubblewrap fingerprint add "<fingerprint>"`. That should update your manifest so your bundle is signed correctly when you build.

Comment: I have used bubblewrap fingerprint add "<fingerprint>" command to generate assetlinks.json